# Installed 15.04, cannot restart ssh daemon

Tags: 15.04, upstart, openssh, systemd

As the title says, I installed 15.04. One of the first things I did was `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`.

The next command was `sudo restart ssh`, which is greeted with an output of:

```
restart: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket 
/com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
```

Googling this error tells me that 15.04 switched from Upstart to systemd, but not how to actually restart my ssh daemon using systemd, or whether that's even possible.

I know it's possible to simply switch back to Upstart, systemwide, but will that break other services that have been changed to use systemd after the release?