# stop Network Manager from Terminal

Tags: 15.10, network-manager

I'm following [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xen) and got as far as the command `sudo stop network-manager` where I received the output `stop: Unable to connect to Upstart`. According to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/649935/installed-15-04-cannot-restart-ssh-daemon/649936#649936?newreg=f56533c299014c9f9c182d0b8b3f034e) I should use the command `sudo systemct1 stop network-manager` but I get the output `sudo: systemct1: command not found`. I tried to update `systemd` but it's already the latest. How do I stop Network Manager from the Terminal?

Running Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: Pretty sure it is `systemctl`and not systemsc1. The last letter is a small L, and not the digit one. Use copy/paste instead of typing.

Comment: Thanks @mikewhatever. Good eye, that's all it was. Works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

type the following:

```
sudo service NetworkManager stop
```

or

```
sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager
```

Comment: I believe it is: `sudo service network-manager stop`. Please check: `ls /etc/init.d`.

Answer (score 1):

**Disabling NetworkManager**

According to [this bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/82335) here's how to disable Network Manager without uninstalling it:

```
sudo stop network-manager
```

Create an override file for the upstart job:

```
echo "manual" | sudo tee /etc/init/network-manager.override
```

[Reference](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager)

However I have no issues stoping it with:

```
sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager
```